# Why are my cucumber tests cases getting skipped?

Tags: java, spring, junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I am using Cucumber testing framing with `spring-rest` web service. I am using standard cucumber JUnit framework and Gradle build tool.
Here are the dependencies

```
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.4')
testCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.4')
testCompile ("info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.2.4")
testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
```

Here is my feature file, location of feature file is `src/main/resources/feature/addition.feature`

```
Feature: Testing a REST API
   Users should be able to add two numbers

Scenario: number addition service
 When baseUri is /messages/add
   Then result should be 3
```

Here is my step definition code. it resides in `test/java/somepackage/`

```
public class StepDefinition {

    @When("^baseUri is (.*)$")
    public void baseUri(String uri) {

    }

    @Then("result should be (\\d+)")
    public void checkResult(int result){
      Assert.assertEquals(result, this.result);
    }
}
```

My test runner class is, test runner and StepDefinition both are in the same package in `/test/java`

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:feature/", glue = {"com.example.restdemo.web.StepDefinition"}, format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"})
public class CucumberIntegrationTest {
}
```

Now when I am running my test runner class i.e `CucumberIntegrationTest.java`, I am getting following O/P.

```
            "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:C:\Users\govindas\Downloads\ideaIU-2017.2.5.win\lib\idea_rt.jar=52114:C:\Users\govindas\Downloads\ideaIU-2017.2.5.win\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\govindas\Downloads\ideaIU-2017.2.5.win\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Users\govindas\Downloads\ideaIU-2017.2.5.win\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\govindas\Downloads\ideaIU-2017.2.5.win\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\govindas\IdeaProjects\restdemo\out\test\classes;C:\Users\govindas\IdeaProjects\restdemo\out\production\classes;C:\Users\govindas\IdeaProjects\restdemo\out\production\resources;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-cache\1.5.7.RELEASE\98480d5e70a79ff279ea0bb156f2d18222ba8211\spring-boot-starter-cache-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-data-rest\1.5.7.RELEASE\cc092ea664a736c5fdf6077dd86f3459bcdd8caa\spring-boot-starter-data-rest-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-hateoas\1.5.7.RELEASE\be7eb70b2ac27fb270278530238323e441afd1cf\spring-boot-starter-hateoas-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\1.5.7.RELEASE\98c652a5461ccbec70b55fd0f7815d9c9a37a082\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-jersey\1.5.7.RELEASE\dc608d6e96755fdad671da5f9a11f86b345fe30d\spring-boot-starter-jersey-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-security\1.5.7.RELEASE\e680aa1a8990a6e98e7a843c88f0a8bc378bb4d\spring-boot-starter-security-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-web\1.5.7.RELEASE\a862305be8b7512a41f6768d825ed37251ccbbe0\spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-test\1.5.7.RELEASE\d23f37a72c2d4e46aba66bc69a649213f9cadeee\spring-boot-starter-test-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\info.cukes\cucumber-spring\1.2.4\f3cff393c13087ac43e11936a90ec0c8792c534\cucumber-spring-1.2.4.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\info.cukes\cucumber-java\1.2.4\57cca534b7abe43f6dd7624b90d3d97d33d3023d\cucumber-java-1.2.4.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.derby\derby\10.13.1.1\29c42babe5c5463c6eea45487d3cfbfe8348ccd1\derby-10.13.1.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\info.cukes\cucumber-junit\1.2.4\8a57b68486cff4da4f10019cb9c62c597a6d2861\cucumber-junit-1.2.4.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.security\spring-security-test\4.2.3.RELEASE\f93339f597290d85a596f25a7841b9109b79ced6\spring-security-test-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\1.5.7.RELEASE\a2e87bf66a1db8037e1feeba7e7063996fa72090\spring-boot-starter-validation-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter\1.5.7.RELEASE\b42fe6962dd8b3be4ac8c1d7134d0ca2d0a35c7e\spring-boot-starter-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-context-support\4.3.11.RELEASE\a74bdcbce2b35804cdfdac1ca820820100b5fd9b\spring-context-support-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-rest-webmvc\2.6.7.RELEASE\9a638b76b290b52a241b59a7341a042a063bad3d\spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-rest-core\2.6.7.RELEASE\fe15f604fa9b35f16af608c05266fcba53a7d17c\spring-data-rest-core-2.6.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.hateoas\spring-hateoas\0.23.0.RELEASE\678ffa0798f417a794fea592dc8066e325611919\spring-hateoas-0.23.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.plugin\spring-plugin-core\1.2.0.RELEASE\f380e7760032e7d929184f8ad8a33716b75c0657\spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.security\spring-security-config\4.2.3.RELEASE\9f3771903616e33521836fd999d63efbfebf90d\spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.security\spring-security-web\4.2.3.RELEASE\7a03e737484ca232d7146852f06d067ac21427ac\spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-webmvc\4.3.11.RELEASE\814f91ec4dc324e724bbe7cbc5045b234604c539\spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.security\spring-security-core\4.2.3.RELEASE\5c0e47a47036c94d6fdd02696bf52be6d1adbd4d\spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure\1.5.7.RELEASE\8bead16b97c9f1b5fe7c47f3e030dd9351a6974d\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-test\1.5.7.RELEASE\b8d77445d48f4320f404d8f13f4e5cb95bc36b30\spring-boot-test-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.5.7.RELEASE\e83f1407ff991e9e7eb156f49fa19d868bb73289\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot\1.5.7.RELEASE\1006870df7b3dc203df7ce84463c5dd7049fdaa4\spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.ext\jersey-spring3\2.25.1\a31bfcd2fcae5beb979d3f41079b6f4020d6fbc9\jersey-spring3-2.25.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2\spring-bridge\2.5.0-b32\f38ecef23edc769942a95c062efd63541044de42\spring-bridge-2.5.0-b32.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-web\4.3.11.RELEASE\50a3dfce550bdf9459dfb2c6282aa104b040258e\spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-context\4.3.11.RELEASE\3efec2d7c7469d49108a2b21c3f15831f7297569\spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.media\jersey-media-json-jackson\2.25.1\19d1e4276eb7b6386640c344d9e5c01eba7eae5d\jersey-media-json-jackson-2.25.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs\jackson-jaxrs-json-provider\2.8.10\f8837cf03871569eb02a491dea64929e5da14b4\jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.8.10.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs\jackson-jaxrs-base\2.8.10\50a3d02a31cb427272a96fe696b5ac9442c7cfa1\jackson-jaxrs-base-2.8.10.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.module\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations\2.8.10\22df8efd0cff7661bf136148c73e2651748f7600\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.10.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.8.10\f7b83cb2bc4b88d53961e749e1ad32f49ef017b7\jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.8.0\45b426f7796b741035581a176744d91090e2e6fb\jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat\tomcat-jdbc\8.5.20\10d0d288d837ddfc92096920e4571054a3934160\tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jdbc\4.3.11.RELEASE\642ed7497d327f299caccb930af6b65e229864c4\spring-jdbc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\1.5.7.RELEASE\eae533e2a0111a51d812912acb3d3e2368736d1b\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.containers\jersey-container-servlet\2.25.1\cf5f7a76fcea38158b890ab7a0142d4db709a882\jersey-container-servlet-2.25.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.containers\jersey-container-servlet-core\2.25.1\400e30bb035a0cdf3c554530224141ce659a0d1e\jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.ext\jersey-bean-validation\2.25.1\1971927d79cad0ad2b5a3bfda24967748a2023d\jersey-bean-validation-2.25.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.core\jersey-server\2.25.1\276e2ee0fd1cdabf99357fce560c5baab675b1a2\jersey-server-2.25.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aop\4.3.11.RELEASE\461d0bb58f1de30203d9331adf4b51de9554de5a\spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2\hk2\2.5.0-b32\c3accae585955e49c771d464899e906ecc9ffb4\hk2-2.5.0-b32.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2\config-types\2.5.0-b32\686bbe7f80b1b879d64c06bc6606c97721a795f2\config-types-2.5.0-b32.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2\hk2-config\2.5.0-b32\dce05ac4225dbc0c1c382ad02e3b5bee51f0168a\hk2-config-2.5.0-b32.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate\hibernate-validator\5.3.5.Final\622a9bcef2eed6d41b5b8e0662c36212009e375\hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.jayway.jsonpath\json-path\2.2.0\22290d17944bd239fabf5ac69005a60a7ecbbbcb\json-path-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.assertj\assertj-core\2.6.0\b532c3fc4f66bcfee4989a3514f1cd56203a33ad\assertj-core-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.mockito\mockito-core\1.10.19\e8546f5bef4e061d8dd73895b4e8f40e3fe6effe\mockito-core-1.10.19.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\4785a3c21320980282f9f33d0d1264a69040538f\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.skyscreamer\jsonassert\1.4.0\9cdbb373a06f6513e51e8c545ee6a5e981463edb\jsonassert-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-test\4.3.11.RELEASE\cf765b5d6d6bdc38c67522ecae3fe9549da43e1\spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-tx\4.3.11.RELEASE\c931ee363d2269f03edfeb83d7d7fe23924ab8a1\spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-commons\1.13.7.RELEASE\cf4538abda1f0a9cf2323d6e4204df0130aeec73\spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-beans\4.3.11.RELEASE\591cc35fd39292adae13f01aa13e978d0bb11936\spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-expression\4.3.11.RELEASE\fca662a2fccdad90ec22b2aaecb021047dcbe249\spring-expression-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-core\4.3.11.RELEASE\eb30ed093f628279d3aead068fd478fa343f1dad\spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\info.cukes\cucumber-core\1.2.4\72790b1da44d8d3d2764c6aef29865ee228bbeb1\cucumber-core-1.2.4.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\1.5.7.RELEASE\c84c4ea09d7f789a0d5e936a961471e5dbd9295e\spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.yaml\snakeyaml\1.17\7a27ea250c5130b2922b86dea63cbb1cc10a660c\snakeyaml-1.17.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.8.10\eb21a035c66ad307e66ec8fce37f5d50fd62d039\jackson-core-2.8.10.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.25\f8c32b13ff142a513eeb5b6330b1588dcb2c0461\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.1.11\ccedfbacef4a6515d2983e3f89ed753d5d4fb665\logback-classic-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\af5364cd6679bfffb114f0dec8a157aaa283b76\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.25\a87bb47468f47ee7aabbd54f93e133d4215769c3\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\da76ca59f6a57ee3102f8f9bd9cee742973efa8a\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat\tomcat-juli\8.5.20\6c0579d329696059f377585d2a51455bf083d9ee\tomcat-juli-8.5.20.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\8.5.20\4df9055507926a2651f691cc9964c50493a0ab29\tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.20\b9026ee20f1f6a2b0fc3e51dd806d800901448b0\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-el\8.5.20\42960f481a8a80f4ffd3b865c2232820e3565bf1\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.20.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.core\jersey-client\2.25.1\4d563b1f93352ee9fad597e9e1daf2c6159993c6\jersey-client-2.25.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.media\jersey-media-jaxb\2.25.1\d7da0beeed5614a3bfd882662faec602699e24b\jersey-media-jaxb-2.25.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.core\jersey-common\2.25.1\2438ce68d4907046095ab54aa83a6092951b4bbb\jersey-common-2.25.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.ext\jersey-entity-filtering\2.25.1\4a5805060f796ec2c9bb1ba0ce91c1db6d889524\jersey-entity-filtering-2.25.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.ws.rs\javax.ws.rs-api\2.0.1\104e9c2b5583cfcfeac0402316221648d6d8ea6b\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2\479c1e06db31c432330183f5cae684163f186146\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2\hk2-core\2.5.0-b32\8cb6a8a9522ec523b7740d29f555bdbe9d936af2\hk2-core-2.5.0-b32.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2\hk2-runlevel\2.5.0-b32\60dc979763ea885e796cba4d3e322af8d500ba74\hk2-runlevel-2.5.0-b32.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2\hk2-locator\2.5.0-b32\195474f8ad0a8d130e9ea949a771bcf1215fc33b\hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2\hk2-api\2.5.0-b32\6a576c9653832ce610b80a2f389374ef19d96171\hk2-api-2.5.0-b32.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2.external\javax.inject\2.5.0-b32\b2fa50c8186a38728c35fe6a9da57ce4cc806923\javax.inject-2.5.0-b32.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\8613ae82954779d518631e05daa73a6a954817d5\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\235ba8b489512805ac13a8f9ea77a1ca5ebe3e8\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss.logging\jboss-logging\3.3.1.Final\c46217ab74b532568c0ed31dc599db3048bd1b67\jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\3d5f48f10bbe4eb7bd862f10c0583be2e0053c6\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.minidev\json-smart\2.2.1\5b9e5df7a62d1279b70dc882b041d249c4f0b002\json-smart-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.objenesis\objenesis\2.1\87c0ea803b69252868d09308b4618f766f135a96\objenesis-2.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.vaadin.external.google\android-json\0.0.20131108.vaadin1\fa26d351fe62a6a17f5cda1287c1c6110dec413f\android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\info.cukes\cucumber-html\0.2.3\624a0c986088e32910336dd77aee5191c04a8201\cucumber-html-0.2.3.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\info.cukes\cucumber-jvm-deps\1.0.5\69ed0efe4b81f05da3c0bdc7281cbdc43f5ceb26\cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\info.cukes\gherkin\2.12.2\17138631fa20fd0e44a13e50d6b7be59cee1a94\gherkin-2.12.2.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.atteo\evo-inflector\1.2.2\2551aad98d65ac5464d81fe05f0e1516cfe471c9\evo-inflector-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged\jersey-guava\2.25.1\a2bb4f8208e134cf2cf71dfb8824e42942f7bd06\jersey-guava-2.25.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2\osgi-resource-locator\1.0.1\4ed2b2d4738aed5786cfa64cba5a332779c4c708\osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2\hk2-utils\2.5.0-b32\5108a926988c4ceda7f1e681dddfe3101454a002\hk2-utils-2.5.0-b32.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2.external\aopalliance-repackaged\2.5.0-b32\6af37c3f8ec6f9e9653ec837eb508da28ce443cd\aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.javassist\javassist\3.21.0-GA\598244f595db5c5fb713731eddbb1c91a58d959b\javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2\class-model\2.5.0-b32\17f054f3e91898c0c0fc52163ad904b13c24e8b\class-model-2.5.0-b32.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.minidev\accessors-smart\1.1\a527213f2fea112a04c9bdf0ec0264e34104cd08\accessors-smart-1.1.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-core\1.1.11\88b8df40340eed549fb07e2613879bf6b006704d\logback-core-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\govindas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.hk2.external\asm-all-repackaged\2.5.0-b32\dc705f1d54cd5a96cbc5a473525e75ef1cb59a9e\asm-all-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar;C:\Users\xyz\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.ow2.asm\asm\5.0.3\dcc2193db20e19e1feca8b1240dbbc4e190824fa\asm-5.0.3.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 com.example.restdemo.web.CucumberIntegrationTest
                    Feature: Testing a REST API
                    Users should be able to add two numbers
                    19:00:03.815 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Registering scope 'cucumber-glue' with implementation [cucumber.runtime.java.spring.GlueCodeScope@2a54a73f]

                    Test ignored.

                    Test ignored.

                    Test ignored.

                    Test ignored.

                    Scenario: number addition service # feature/addition.feature:4
                    When baseUri is /messages/add
                    Then result should be 3

                    1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
                    2 Steps (2 undefined)
                    0m0.000s


                    You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

            @When("^baseUri is /messages/add$")
            public void baseuri_is_messages_add() throws Throwable {
                    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
                    throw new PendingException();
                    }

            @Then("^result should be (\\d+)$")
            public void result_should_be(int arg1) throws Throwable {
                    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
                    throw new PendingException();
                    }


                    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the class name from the glue attribute

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:feature/", glue = {"com.example.restdemo.web"}, format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"})
```